# Python - GUI linking multiple Frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Very new to working with GUI's so was wondering if someone could give me some guidance on how to link multiple frames so you can press a button to go to that frame.

If anyone has an ideas or suggestions that would be great!

```
from tkinter import *

class main(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master=None):
       super(main, self).__init__(master)    
       self.grid()
       self.pack()
   def buttons_dash():
      # create first button
       self.bttn1_dash = Button(self, text = "Student Login",)
       self.bttn1_dash.grid()
       self.bttn1_dash.config(height=3, width=30)

       # create second button
       self.bttn2_dash = Button(self)
       self.bttn2_dash.grid()   
       self.bttn2_dash.configure(text = "Staff Login")
       self.bttn2_dash.config(height=3, width=30)

       # create third button
       self.bttn3_dash = Button(self)
       self.bttn3_dash.grid()
       self.bttn3_dash["text"] = "Exit"
       self.bttn3_dash.config(height=3, width=30)
       self.bttn3_dash = Button(self, text= "Exit")

class student_dashboard(Frame):
      def __init__(self, master=None):
       super(main, self).__init__(master)    
       self.grid()
       self.pack()
      def buttons_student():
       #create first button
       self.bttn1_student = Button(self, text = "View Highscores")
       self.bttn1_student.grid()
       self.bttn1_student.config(height=3, width=30)

       # create second button
       self.bttn2_student = Button(self)
       self.bttn2_student.grid()    
       self.bttn2_student.configure(text = "Save Score")
       self.bttn2_student.config(height=3, width=30)

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Dashboard")
app = main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any research? There are many questions similar to this on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a button in your main class with a command calling a function which contains a nested class and new tkinter frame then you'll have a nested top-level.

```
import tkinter as tk
class main:
    def __init__(self, root1):
        self.root1=root1
        self.frame1=tk.Frame(root1)
        self.button_spawn_top=tk.Button(text="spawn_frame",
        command=self.new_window)
        self.button_spawn_top.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    def new_window(self):
        class NewWindow:
            def __init__(self, root2):
                self.root2=root2
                self.frame2=tk.Frame(root2)
                self.label2=tk.Label(text='new_window')
                self.label2.grid(row=0,column=0)
                self.frame2.grid(row=0,column=0)
        root2=tk.Toplevel()
        app2=NewWindow(root2)
root1=tk.Tk()
app1=main(root1)
root1.mainloop()
```